# Gap between div elements

Tags: html, css

I was hoping for some help with a problem involving some divs.

I am doing a Udemy course to recreate the BBC website and I've got to a point where I have some divs with content but there is a gap between them.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;}

#topbar { 
    width: 1050px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 40px;}
 
#bbclogo {
    margin-top: 8px;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
 
.topbar-section {
    float:left;
    border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    height: 100%;
}
 
#signinimage {
    margin: 10px 15px;
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
} 
 
#signin-text {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: relative;
    top: 12px;
    padding-right: 65px;
}      

#signin-div {
    float:left;
} 
 
#wiggly-line {
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
}

#bello-image {
    height: 26px;
    margin: 7px 15px 7px 12px;
    float: left;
} 
 
.topbar-menu {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 13px 13px 0 13px;
    height: 27px;
}

#more-arrow {
    height: 4px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

#searchbox {
    background-color: #E4E4E4;
    border: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 8px 0 8px 8px;
    float: left;
} 

#magnifying-glass {
    margin-top: 8px;
    height: 27px;
} 

.clear {
    clear: both;
} 

#menu-bar-container {
    background-color: #BB1919;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
} 

#menu-bar {
    width: 1050px;
    margin: 0 auto;
} 

h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-top: 10px;
    float: left;
} 

#local-news {
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid #BB4545;
    width: 175px;
    margin: 15px 10px;
    padding: 5px 5px 4px 5px;
} 

#local-news a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
}
 
#local-news:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#local-news img {
    height: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

#menu-bar-container-2 {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #A91717;
    display: block;
} 

#menu-bar-2 {
    width: 1050px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 35px;
    display: block;
}       

#menu-bar-2 a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 16px;
    border-right: 1px solid #BB4545;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    top: 9px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="topbar">
    <!--white top bar-->
    <img id="bbclogo" src="Images\bbclogo.png"/>
    <!--left border div with classes-->
    <div id="signin-div" class="topbar-section"></div> 
 
    <!--Signin image-->
    <div id="signin-div">
        <img id="signinimage" src="Images\signinimage.png"/>
        <span id="signin-text">Sign in</span>
    </div>
 
    <!--Bell div-->
    <div id="bell-div">
        <img id="wiggly-line" src="Images/pointed_line.png"/>
        <img id="bello-image" src="Images/bell.png"/>
    </div>
    <!--Menubar links-->
    <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">News</div>
    <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">Sport</div>
    <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">Weather</div>
    <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">iPlayer</div>
    <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">TV</div>
    <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">Radio</div>
    <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">More
        <img id="more-arrow" src="Images/arrow.png"/>
    </div>
 
    <!--Search bar-->
    <div class="topbar-section">
        <input id="searchbox" type="text" placeholder="Search">
        <input type="image" id="magnifying-glass" src="Images/glass.png"/>
    </div>
 
</div>
<!--To clear previous floats-->
<div class="clear"></div>

<!--Menu bar-->
<div id="menu-bar-container">
    <div id="menu-bar">
        <h1>NEWS</h1>
        <div id="local-news">
            <a href="">Find local news</a>
            <img src="Images/pointer.png">
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
<!--Menu bar 2-->
<div id="menu-bar-container-2">
    <div id="menu-bar-2">
        <a href="">Home</a>
        <a href="">UK</a>
        <a href="">World</a>
        <a href="">Business</a>
        <a href="">Politics</a>
        <a href="">Tech</a>
        <a href="">Science</a>
        <a href="">Health</a>
        <a href="">Education</a>
        <a href="">Entertainent & Arts</a>
        <a href="">Video & Audio</a>
        <a href="">More</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried playing around with various things (changing display, floating, trying to clear previous divs...) but I can't seem to figure out the problem. I was hoping for some advice about what I am doing wrong.

I read somewhere that whitespace between divs can sometimes be an issue. Could this be the problem?

(strangely, when I created the code snippet above, the gap was not showing in the results window but when I try it in Chrome, IE or Firefox, the problem occurs)

Many thanks in advance

Comment: So try removing the whitespace by changing to `</div><div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">` (without the line break and indention in between).

Comment: Which divs have the gap? They all look fine here though you do have a severe case of Iditis.

Comment: Are you using a css reset?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your responses. Sirko - I tried to remove the whitespace but it hasn't had any effect sadly. R Reveley - the gap is between the menu-bar-container and menu-bar-container-2. I am also not using a CSS reset (as far as I am aware, unless the browser is using its own, possibly why there is a difference between the results in my browsers and when the code snippet is run). Here is the link to what it looks like https://s30.postimg.org/5z0l8zfht/snip.png

Comment: Hello. I have found the problem and face-palmed myself. I increased the height of the menu-bar-container and that seemed to fix it. I'm not entirely sure why the next div didn't float up directly underneath it but it seems to have done the trick. Many thanks for your time and advice

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the advice on my problem.

As mentioned in my last comment, it was the height of the div which was creating the gap (it wasn't tall enough). I think this was due to another element's padding pushing the lower div down, so when I increased the height it brought everything into alignment.

I'm still learning a lot about web development and I am grateful for the responses. I'm sure I'll be learning a lot more along the way. Many thanks!

Comment: You should't reply yourself with an answer to your question